# How to send SMS using Twilio in my android application?

Tags: android, sms, twilio

In my android application I have created one button, when I had pressed on the button I want to send message.So for that I have created one java class and written twilio code.

```
final TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(
                        ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

                // Get the main account (The one we used to authenticate the
                // client)
                final Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();

                final SmsFactory messageFactory = mainAccount.getSmsFactory();
                final Map<String, String> messageParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                messageParams.put("To", "+912342423423");
                messageParams.put("From", "+132432432434");
                messageParams.put("Body", "This is my message");
                try {
                    messageFactory.create(messageParams);
                } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

when I am using the above code it showing some error like  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager`

I have added only one jar file in lib folder as `" twilio-java-sdk-3.3.10-jar-with-dependencies.jar ".`

please tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used HttpPost method to [send sms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) in that i have passed my url with base authentication here is my code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{ACCOUNT_SID}/SMS/Messages");
        String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic "
                            + Base64.encodeToString(
                                    (ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(),
                                    Base64.NO_WRAP);

                    httppost.setHeader("Authorization",
                            base64EncodedCredentials);
                    try {

                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From",
                                "+123424353534"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To",
                                "+914342423434"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body",
                                "Welcome to Twilio"));

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                nameValuePairs));

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        System.out.println("Entity post is: "
                                + EntityUtils.toString(entity));


                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                }
```

It is working well.

Comment: I have used your code to send SMS in my own number but response is always like "<From>+15005550006</From><Body>Sent from your Twilio trial account - Welcome to Twilio</Body><Status>queued</Status><Direction>outbound-api</Direction><ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion><Price/><PriceUnit>USD</PriceUnit>" But I didnt get the SMS. Please why this happen ? I am using test credentials.

Comment: yes status is queued, so it will come after sometime, when I am testing my app at that time also, I got same response.

Comment: having Illegal character at 
"https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{my-_ACCOUNT_SID}/SMS/Messages");
line?

Answer (score 7):

This solution with Retrofit

```
public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "accountSId";
public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "authToken";

private void sendMessage() {
    String body = "Hello test";
    String from = "+...";
    String to = "+...";

    String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
            (ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP
    );

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("From", from);
    data.put("To", to);
    data.put("Body", body);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/")
            .build();
    TwilioApi api = retrofit.create(TwilioApi.class);

    api.sendMessage(ACCOUNT_SID, base64EncodedCredentials, data).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) Log.d("TAG", "onResponse->success");
            else Log.d("TAG", "onResponse->failure");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onFailure");
        }
    });
}

interface TwilioApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Accounts/{ACCOUNT_SID}/SMS/Messages")
    Call<ResponseBody> sendMessage(
            @Path("ACCOUNT_SID") String accountSId,
            @Header("Authorization") String signature,
            @FieldMap Map<String, String> metadata
    );
}
```

Dependencies for `build.gradle`
`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'`

Comment: ResponseBody inside new Callback<ResponseBody>() giving error

Comment: The API url no longer wants the /SMS part of the path. You can cut that part out, as seen here:
https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/api-explorer/sms/messages/create

Answer (score 7):

My method, using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/):

**1. Prerequisites**

Gradle:

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Permission in activity:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build() );
}
```

**2. Code**

```
private void sendSms(String toPhoneNumber, String message){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+ACCOUNT_SID+"/SMS/Messages";
    String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("From", fromPhoneNumber)
            .add("To", toPhoneNumber)
            .add("Body", message)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .header("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials)
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.d(TAG, "sendSms: "+ response.body().string());
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

*I used Allu code for generathing authorization in header*

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Java SDK has third party dependencies without them it is not going to work. The dependencies are:
1. Httpcore
2. Httpclient
3. Commons lang
4. Json simple
5. Jackson
Not quite sure if you need them all, but at least now you are missing httpcore

Comment: If i have added those "httpcore or httpclient jar" files then it is showing the error is "Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;" means same classes or same packages are avialble in twilio-sdk-java jar file.So it is showing duplicate classes is available

Comment: The twilio-sdk-java jar does not have this class, the class which you have mention only available in httpcore.jar, so maybe you have more then one version of httpcore available ?

Comment: I have added those jar files like "twilio-java-sdk-3.3.10.jar,httpcore.jar,httpclient-4.3.jar" and the class "org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager" present in httpclient-4.3.jar but it is showing the same error the Log-cat is displaying like this

Comment: unable to resolve direct method 13784: Lorg/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
 replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0024
 DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3250 at 0x2e in Lcom/twilio/sdk/TwilioRestClient;
 Shutting down VM
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430d4140)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.simplesmstest, 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:137)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:108)

Comment: Please tell me where i can find the brief description to get Twilio in my android application,i am very confusing about twilio.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the BasicPhone project of Twilio SDK. I've tried this to call and now I can call too. This project has all the methods and functions that you need to call and to send SMS. First of all, you need a PHP web service to get capability token and pass that PHP script into your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my need.
        public class TwilioAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
        Context context;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        public TwilioAsyncTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            //
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC_yourACCOUNT_SID_9b/SMS/Messages");
            String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(
                    (ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);

            httppost.setHeader("Authorization",
                    base64EncodedCredentials);
            try {

                int randomPIN = (int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
                String randomVeriValue = "" + randomPIN;
// these are for control in other anctivity used sharepreference 
                editorTwilio.putString("twilio_veri_no", randomVeriValue);
                editorTwilio.commit();

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From",
                        "+148******")); // what number they gave you
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To",
                        "+90" + phoneNo)); // your phone or our customers
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body",
                        "Your verification number is : " + randomVeriValue));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                System.out.println("Entity post is: "
                        + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                // Util.showMessage(mParentAct, "Welcome");


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            //
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", " Wait for ");

        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
            // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
            // progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
        }

    }


    And call your Task


TwilioAsyncTask task = new TwilioAsyncTask(CountryAndPhone.this);
                        task.execute();
```